# Sum of $\sum_{n>0} (1+ \frac{1}{n})x^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need to calculate the sum of this power series and i don't know how

$\sum_{n>0} (1+ \frac{1}{n})x^n$

I will appreciate a hint. Thanks

Comment: I guess the idea is to split it in two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ (1+\frac {1}{n})x^n = x^n + \frac {x^n}{n} $$

So you  have two series to add up.

The first one is the geometric series and the second on is anti -derivative of a geometric series.

You can evaluate both easily.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you can evaluate the sum $\sum_{n > 0} x^n$ for $|x| < 1$.

Very formally you have $$\sum_{n > 0} \frac 1n x^n = \sum_{n > 0} \int_0^x t^{n-1} \, dt = \int_0^x \sum_{n > 0} t^{n-1} \, dt$$
so that if you can justify the formal calculation you can evaluate your sum with an antiderivative.

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (1+\frac{1}{n})x^n=A+B$

$A=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n=\frac{x}{1-x}$

$B=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}$

$\frac{dB}{dx}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n-1}=\frac{1}{1-x}$

Integrate to get $B=-ln(1-x)+C$.  Since $B(0)=0$, $C=0$

Final result $A+B=\frac{x}{1-x}-ln(1-x)$

Comment: OP asked for a *hint*.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers tell you what to do assuming $|x|<1$. For completeness,
let's prove that the series converges if and only if $|x|<1$.

Writing the series as $\sum a_{n}$, note that
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}=\frac{1+\frac{1}{n+1}}{1+\frac{1}{n}}\frac{x^{n+1}}{x^{n}}=\frac{n^{2}+2n}{n^{2}+2n+1}x.
$$
and hence
$$
\lim\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right|=\left|x\right|.
$$
By the ratio test, the series converges if $|x|<1$ and diverges if $|x|>1$. 
Clearly, the series *also* diverges if $x=1$ since $\sum(1+\frac{1}{n})1^{n}=\sum(1+\frac{1}{n})\geq\sum1$.
The remaining case of $x=-1$ involves a bit more work...

Fix $x=-1$ and suppose $\sum a_{n}$ converges.
Noting that 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(-1\right)^{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)=(-1)^{N}+\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(-1\right)^{n}\frac{1}{n},
$$
our assumption implies that the term on the right hand side above should also converge.
However, note that $(-1)^{N}$ diverges while $\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(-1\right)^{n}\frac{1}{n}$ converges (to $-\log2$).
Therefore, $\sum a_{n}$ diverges.